# LaTeX prevent oversized table from getting cut off

Tags: tables, width

I have a LaTeX file with a very wide table with many many columns. When I compile this and convert to pdf, the right part of the table is cut off because it is too big to fit on a page.

Is there a way to either

1. extend the size of the page to avoid cutoff
2. reduce the size of the table text such that the entire table can fit on a page

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: 1) Assuming you're working in portrait orientation, you can gain some space by rotating your table by 90 degrees, for instance using the `sidewaystable` environment from the `rotating` package. 2) If the paper size isn't fixed, you can increase it (using the `geometry` package) until your table fits. 3) If the paper size *is* fixed, you have to ask yourself: "is that the best way I can present information to my readers?" Perhaps it would be wise to break that big table into several smaller ones.

Answer (score 3):

In response to part 2 of the user's question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\parindent 0in\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
Textwidth:\\
\rule{\textwidth}{0.3ex}\par
First, let's create an oversized table:\par
\def\x{%
\begin{tabular}{|p{2in}|p{2in}|p{1.5in}|}
\hline
First column & Second column & Third Column \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}
\x\par
Now I will scale the table to 79 percent of original\par
\scalebox{.79}{\x}
\end{document}
```

[image]